# Suppose $(a^2+3ab+3b^2-1)|(a+b^3)$. Find all integer solutions for $a$ and $b$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $a$ and $b$ are positive integers. Suppose $(a^2+3ab+3b^2-1)|(a+b^3)$.

Show $k^3 | (a^2+3ab+3b^2-1)$, where $k>1$ and $k$ is some positive integer. Further, find all possible integer solutions for $a$ and $b$.

My attempt is to let $(a^2+3ab+3b^2-1)t=(a+b^3)$, so we got a quadratic equation with respect to $a$, use Vieta's formula we got the sum for two roots $a_1+a_2=-3b+\frac{1}{t}$. If we assume both roots are integers, then $t=1$. Further discussion gives: $a=n^3-3n+1, b=n^2+n-1$ where $n\ge2$

Question is: $a_1+a_2=-3b+\frac{1}{t}$, maybe only one root is integer and another root is rational, which means $t$ could be $2, 3, 4,...$, so how to find integer solutions for other cases of $t$, or how to exclude other cases?

Comment: Please re-check the problem.  I can prove that $(a^2+3ab+3b^2-1)$ divides  *some* $k^3$ but I can not yet prove that *some* $k^3$ divides $(a^2+3ab+3b^2-1)$.  Are you sure that you copied the problem down correctly?

Comment: Sorry for the ignorance, but I'm confused with your question and answer.  You've found out what both $a$ and $b$ are; but how does that prove $k^3 | (a^2 + 3ab + 3b^2 - 1)$?

Comment: plug in a and b to the expression and it will give the $n^3$ factor @ewong

Comment: the problem is correct. @user2661923

Comment: Apparently this is from 2019 Canadian Mathematical Olympiad, Problem 2 (https://www2.cms.math.ca/Competitions/CMO/archive/exam2019.pdf). It is solved at https://www2.cms.math.ca/Competitions/CMO/archive/sol2019.pdf and at https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1811659p12071386

Comment: Thank you, but how to find a formula for all integers of a and b? I can only find when $t=1$ case, what about other cases? @GerryMyerson

Comment: I don't know. Have you looked at all those links? If it's not there, it may be a hard problem.

Comment: Those links are for the proof, but not for searching a general formula for a and b @GerryMyerson

Comment: OK, so here's a suggestion: write a program to find all solutions with $a,b$ up to, say, $1000$, and look for patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an answer, but it may shed some light on the problem, and it's too long for a comment.

Let's look at $$(a^2+3ab+3b^2-1)t=a+b^3$$ For any given nonzero integer $t$, we can make some substitutions to get this into the form $y^2={\rm a\ cubic\ in\ }x$. Such an equation is, in general, an *elliptic curve*, also known as a curve of *genus one*, and a theorem of Siegel states that it has only finitely many solutions in integers $x,y$ (where "finitely many" could be none at all). Given an elliptic curve, it's not all that easy to find all the integer solutions, or even to determine whether it has any. Usually, some high-powered math is involved. As $t$ varies, we have a *family* of elliptic curves, and it's generally even harder to find all the solutions, or to show there are none.

Now, $t=1$ is an exception. Let $f(a,b)=a^2+3ab+3b^2-1-a-b^3$, and let $g(a,b)=f(a-1,b+1)=a^2+3ab-b^3$. Then $g(0,0)=0$, and both the partial derivative of $g$ with respect to $a$ and the partial derivative of $g$ with respect to $b$ vanish at $(0,0)$, so there is a singular point at the origin, and $g(a,b)=0$ is of genus zero, and not an elliptic curve. A line through the origin with slope $r$, $a=br$, intersects the graph of $g(a,b)=0$ at $(0,0)$ and at $(a,b)=(t^3+3t^2,t^2+3t)$, giving rise to an infinity of integer solutions – translating back to $f(a,b)$, this gives the infinite family of solutions OP found.

Whether there are solutions for other values of $t$ is, as already noted, probably a harder problem because they will probably be sporadic and not come in nice infinite families. In addition to running a computer on it to see whether there are any smallish solutions, it may be a good idea to post to MathOverflow, where users should have more to say about the mathematics of families of elliptic curves.

Comment: I see, thank you very much for mentioning this!

Comment: @MathFail Excluding $t=1$, a computer search finds that for every $t$, there are four integer $b$ such that the quadratic $(a^2 + 3a b + 3b^2 - 1)t - (a + b^3) = 0$ has an integer root $a$. These are $b = (1,\, t,\, 3t-2,\, 3t+2)$. Unfortunately, $a$ is a _negative_ integer. <Sigh>. So that leaves only your $t=1$.